# How can i seperate these in a list?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, calculation

so i have a text file named "1011.txt" with these things written into it:
1011 7:30
1011 14:25
1011 8:00
1011 18:20
1011 7:45
1011 17:21

i want to bring it into my python file, so i use read and splitlines to make it into a list.(i cant do anything else, i HAVE to make it into a list)

so i now have to split the "code" which is "1011" and the work hours which are the numbers after 1011.i have to seperate them with loops(i have to also separate the hour and the minute.)
does anybody know how i can do this?
i want to turn them into separate items in a list

so far this my code:

```
r1 = open("1011.txt")

l1 = r1.read().splitlines()
print(l1)
for hours in range(len(l1)):
    print ((l1[hours]))
r1.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.split` can be used here:

```py
for line in l1:
    code, time = line.split()
    hour, minute = time.split(':')
    print(code, hour, minute)
```

Comment: Great answer, almost exactly what I was typing up. As a final addendum, OP may wish to look into `with` statements as a means of opening files

Comment: thanks! but how do i put them in a list?

Comment: @Parsa Well, you can declare a list outside the loop (`l = []`), then call append in the loop (adding tuples): `l.append((code, hour, minute))`.

Comment: @Unmitigated thanks, but now i gotta figure out a way to calculate the work hours between :(

Comment: @Parsa That's a different issue, so if you're stuck with implementing it, I recommend asking a new question.